# Hide div content via pseudo element

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple **minesweeper game** using css and js.
I managed to create the grid, place bombs, and count the number of bombs in the adjacent cells.

I'm having some **issue at hiding the cell content** till the player click on of them.

My initial idea was to use a pseudo-element, and after failing i tried to stack a div on top of each cell.
I failed twice, so here I am :)
Please try to give as less help as possible. 
**What I'm trying to achieve now, is to create a sort of mask on top of each cell**. 
I'll take care of removing it later.

Thanks!

In the Js, there's a comment where i create a children div and applied a `.mask` on it.

In the css you can find the `.mask` class

I'd like to make it by using a pseudo class.

```js
function start(n) {
    // place bombs
    if(n > 30) { n = 30; }
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("game-cell");
    gameCells = Array.from(nodeList);
    var totalCells = gameCells.length;
    while(n > 0 ) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalCells);
        gameCells[index].classList.add('bomb');
        gameCells.splice(index, 1)
        totalCells--;
        n--;
    }

    //place numbers
    var cellsAbove = [-11, -10, -9];
    var cellsBelow = [9, 10, 11];
    var cellsOnLeft = [-11, -1, 9];
    var cellsOnRight = [-9, 1, 11];
    gameCells = Array.from(nodeList);
    gameCells.forEach( (cell, idx, arr) => {
        if(!cell.classList.contains('bomb')) {
            var toIgnore = [];
            if (idx<10)     { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsAbove);  }
            if (idx>=90)    { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsBelow);  }
            if (idx%10===0) { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsOnLeft); }
            if (idx%10===9) { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsOnRight);}
            var adjacentCells = [-11, -10, -9, -1, 1, 9, 10, 11]
                .filter( c => toIgnore.indexOf(c) < 0)
                .map( c => c+idx)
                .map( c => arr[c]);
            var bombNumber = adjacentCells.map( c => c.classList.contains('bomb') ? 1 : 0).reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0);
            if(bombNumber>0) gameCells[idx].innerText = bombNumber
        }
    });

    //mask cells 
    gameCells.forEach( n => {
        var mask = document.createElement("div");         
        mask.classList.add('mask')
        n.appendChild(mask); 
    })
}

start(10);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


.game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 15% repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    row-gap: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;

}

.game-header {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1 /-1;
}

.game-cell {
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.game-cell:hover {
    border-color: #4ca4a9;  
}
 
.bomb {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.mask {
    /* background-color: gray; */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="game-container">
        <header class="game-header"> My Game </header>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: position: relative; on .game-cell ?

Comment: yes it was enough. i always forget that the position prop work on the first positioned  ancestor

Comment: but i'd like to make it by using a pseudo class, is that possible?

Comment: @TemaniAfif you just set this as duplicate but it's not answering my question. I was looking for  a way to make it via pseudo element

Comment: you said it *was enough* so I closed as duplicate ... I was waiting for your reply to close

Comment: to use pseudo element simply move the mask class to the element then add pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/6xga3L0z/

Comment: that's actually the answer! thanks!

Comment: added more duplicate explaining pseudo elements too

Comment: Well done man! Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `position: absolute;` on the `.mask` class, you need a `position:relative;` position reference for it, which - if I understood your question correctly - should be applied to the `.game-cell` class.

```js
function start(n) {
    // place bombs
    if(n > 30) { n = 30; }
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("game-cell");
    gameCells = Array.from(nodeList);
    var totalCells = gameCells.length;
    while(n > 0 ) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalCells);
        gameCells[index].classList.add('bomb');
        gameCells.splice(index, 1)
        totalCells--;
        n--;
    }

    //place numbers
    var cellsAbove = [-11, -10, -9];
    var cellsBelow = [9, 10, 11];
    var cellsOnLeft = [-11, -1, 9];
    var cellsOnRight = [-9, 1, 11];
    gameCells = Array.from(nodeList);
    gameCells.forEach( (cell, idx, arr) => {
        if(!cell.classList.contains('bomb')) {
            var toIgnore = [];
            if (idx<10)     { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsAbove);  }
            if (idx>=90)    { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsBelow);  }
            if (idx%10===0) { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsOnLeft); }
            if (idx%10===9) { toIgnore = toIgnore.concat(cellsOnRight);}
            var adjacentCells = [-11, -10, -9, -1, 1, 9, 10, 11]
                .filter( c => toIgnore.indexOf(c) < 0)
                .map( c => c+idx)
                .map( c => arr[c]);
            var bombNumber = adjacentCells.map( c => c.classList.contains('bomb') ? 1 : 0).reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0);
            if(bombNumber>0) gameCells[idx].innerText = bombNumber
        }
    });

    //mask cells 
    gameCells.forEach( n => {
        var mask = document.createElement("div");         
        mask.classList.add('mask')
        n.appendChild(mask); 
    })
}

start(10);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


.game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 15% repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    row-gap: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;

}

.game-header {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1 /-1;
}

.game-cell {
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position:relative;
}

.game-cell:hover {
    border-color: #4ca4a9;  
}
 
.bomb {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.mask {
    /* background-color: gray; */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-container">
        <header class="game-header"> My Game </header>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
        <div class="game-cell"></div>
    </div>
```

P.S.: In the code of your question's snippet, you are *not*  using a pseudo element, so maybe you should change the title of your question...

Comment: thanks for the fix!
Is there any way to do it using a pseudo element?